# Exponent-like power series with coefficients of increasing complexity

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, exponential-function

How one deals with series like this one:
$zb + \frac{z^2}{2!}b^2(1+\frac{c}{b}) + \frac{z^3}{3!}b^3(1+\frac{2c}{b})(1+\frac{c}{b}) + \frac{z^4}{4!}b^4(1+\frac{3c}{b})(1+\frac{2c}{b})(1+\frac{c}{b})+...$?

The coefficients' complexity increases but in a highly "predictable" way.

Comment: In what type of 'deal'? What should be done with it?

Comment: It should be a closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), your series is$$\sum_{z\ge1}\left(\frac{(cz)^k}{k!}\frac1b\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{b}{c}+j\right)\right)=\frac{{}_1F_0(\frac{b}{c};\,cz)-1}{b}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what was needed.